# afollestad materialdialogs library gradle sync fail due to exploded aapt file

Tags: android, gradle

I've came across following library
https://github.com/afollestad/material-dialogs
and i have tried to add the dependencies to my project but gradle consistently fails to sync saying that some .aapt file exploded or something 
Can some one please guide me on how to add this library correctly and screenshots of how to do it would be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you add this in build.gradle(Project) (you need to paste this two times - there are two repositoies blocks).

```
repositories {
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
}
```

And this to other build.gradle(Module:app)

```
compile('com.github.afollestad.material-dialogs:core:0.8.5.1@aar') {
        transitive = true
    }
```

Comment: 2 times??  well i did not paste that maven repo part in buildscript .. is that a possible cause??

Comment: yes, add it inside buildscript and allpojects block, and try sync

Comment: Nop didnt work ... Following message flooded the message tab    Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':app:_debugCompile'.
   > Could not find com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1.
     Searched in the following locations:
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/23.1.1/appcompat-v7-23.1.1.pom
         https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/23.1.1/appcompat-v7-23.1.1.jar
         https://jitpack.io/com/android/support/appcompat-v7/23.1.1/appcompat-v7-23.1.1.pom

Comment: This is weird: Could not find com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1.

You didn't delete jcenter() that was previously there in repositories blocks?

Comment: Nop all other dependencies are all good but this one is making everything aweful.. and ive got the following warning as well ..                 Warning:Module version com.github.afollestad:material-dialogs:0.8.5.1 depends on libraries but is a jar

Comment: Do you have compile com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1 under dependecies, it should be there by default?

Comment: Oops i've got 21.1.2 appcomapct , that must be the cause,

Comment: no problem, in case you wonder what happened: dev that build this materialdialogs libary uploaded it at maven repository (which by default isn't included in gradle), so you had to include it. Next, that dev used 23.1.1 appcompat library inside his library, so you need to include that library too.